# Looking for source codes of silverlight application that uses PRISM framework

Tags: silverlight, enterprise-library

I'm new in silverlight and prism framework and I want to explore some working silverlight applications that are based on prism.

Comment: Prism itself comes with some samples (although of dubious quality). You can check these out in case you missed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the included samples, there's an interesting set of articles [here](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2009/10/03/mvvm-with-prism-101-ndash-part-1-the-bootstrapper.aspx), complete with source code.

There's also some source at [Elegant Code](http://elegantcode.com/2009/06/05/bsdg-prismmvvm-for-wpf-presentation-sample-code/) which I found useful, as well as a whole list of examples and tutorials at [Patterns and Practices Guidance](http://www.pnpguidance.net/category/Prism.aspx).

Also be aware that there are [many alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974802/what-are-the-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-various-mvvm-frameworks-for-silverlight) to Prisim, and you could always write your own simple MVVM architecture if you were interested in learning more about it. For more information, Jeremy Likeness has a great article over at code project about the architecture, entitled [MVVM Explained](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/mvvm-explained.aspx). I found this to be hugely helpful when developing my first Silverlight MVVM application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Prism [hands-on labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405475%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx) and [quickstarts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921141%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx) (make sure to scroll to the bottom of the page):

Also, you may find [this episode on Understanding the Value of Prism](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Understanding-the-Value-of-Prism-Silverlight-TV-37) useful.